# Is Miss America Organization the world's largest provider of scholarship assistance for young women?

Tags: finance, school

The [official website for Miss America Organization](http://www.missamerica.org/scholarships/purpose.aspx) claims:

> The Miss America Organization is one of the nation's leading
>   achievement programs and the **world's largest provider of scholarship
>   assistance for young women**. Last year, the Miss America Organization
>   and its state and local organizations made available more than $45
>   million in cash and scholarship assistance. This assistance is not
>   just for the handful of young women who become Miss America, but is
>   available to the over 12,000 young women who compete in the state and
>   local competitions as well.

Is Miss America Organization  the world's largest provider of scholarship assistance for young women?

Comment: This is clearly inspired by [Last Week Tonight](http://time.com/3418349/john-oliver-miss-america-pageant-scholarships/) report of a few days ago. Are you skeptical of John Oliver's report?

Comment: @Oddthinking Hmm yeah probably the source of inspiration of the guy who posted this on Facebook. Interesting report, thanks! That explains the ending 'lol'. But at 11:45 in the video, John does say even though the true number is around $4 million or somewhere below, it is still the largest women-only scholarship they could find, which I find surprising.

Comment: A nice effect of Oliver's reporting is that the Society of Women Engineers received $25K in scholarship donations the following week: http://time.com/3426950/john-oliver-women-scholarships/

Comment: What is the *exact* claim? Are we only looking at programs that target specifically women, or which broader program gives the most money to women for college? If it's women-only, this doesn't surprise me, since most schlarship programs aren't limited to a single sex/gender. The US govt gives out [far more](http://fedmoney.org/grants/0-scholarships.htm) to women in general. Even if you just look at a [*single* veteran program](http://fedmoney.org/grants/64027-00-post-9-11-veterans-educational-assistance), they paid out over **8B USD** in FY 11. I'm sure more than $45M of that went to women.

Comment: @Geobits The exact claim is reproduced in the question, and is vague enough not to distinguish between the two scenarios, so I'd imagine a good answer would speak to both. That might be how they're getting away with that claim: it may be true that they're the largest sex-limited scholarship program aimed at women but phrased it to mislead the reader into thinking they're the largest overall provider to women.

Comment: If you actually watched the John Oliver report, you will see that he pretty clearly explained why Miss America did not pay $45m in scholarships last year. (Short answer: most of the money they 'made available' was under circumstances where only a tiny, tiny fraction of it could be claimed). However the program also said they believed it possible that Miss America was *still* the largest provider of women-only scholarships, even with the massively reduced figure. SO: Are you asking us to verify the $45m figure, or  whether they are still the largest provider of scholarships?

Comment: @DJ Latter option.